# c2dm in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, android-c2dm

I'm working on building a c2dm module for my Titanium project. (I actually want gcm, but the only change is to the sender_id, so that shouldn't be a problem).

However, I'm running into a lot of trouble when trying this. I tried using the module [Kuraturpa](https://github.com/Kuraturpa/titanium-c2dm) wrote, but I can't get it to build(compilation error), and it doesn't include any .jar file for some reason. I tried following [this](http://technoblog-bhushan.blogspot.com/2012/03/looking-at-all-possible-solution-for.html) guide, but I again ran into some build errors (this time, exec returns 2, apparently because it can't find gpref?)

Has anyone actually successfully gotten c2dm to work with 2.1.0.GA? Can they share that success? I can't believe this is this difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it to work by installing the macosx developer tools for c/c++ development from the apple website. Once that was installed, I had gperf, and the build worked for the given module.

As far as converting c2dm to GCM, that was dead simple.